# Can we not change status of Job from Closed to Open?

Tags: apex, apexrest, bulk-api

Can we not change status of Job from `Closed` to `Open`?

I somehow (unintentionally) change the status of the job, but now I unable to change the status to Open again. Is this not possible to change the status?

When I;m trying to change the status, I see

```
{"exceptionCode":"InvalidJobState","exceptionMessage":"Job State cannot be update to 'Open"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer **No**.

If the job is closed then

> No new batches can be added to this job. Batches associated with the job may be processed after a job is closed. You cannot edit or save a closed job.

For more information, refer [JobInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_reference_jobinfo.htm)

Comment: That was link I was looking for :p